# Execute external method from Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, methods, execute

I have created this on Oracle `12c`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE LOG_SAL_TEST IS
  PROCEDURE log_sal(
    emp_id          IN  NUMBER,
    old_sal         IN  NUMBER,
    new_sal         IN NUMBER
  );
END LOG_SAL_TEST;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY LOG_SAL_TEST AS
  PROCEDURE log_sal(
    emp_id          IN  NUMBER,
    old_sal         IN  NUMBER,
    new_sal         IN NUMBER
  ) AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'com.sth.ctt.business.cases.control.CaseWatch.logSal(int, float, float)';
END LOG_SAL_TEST;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER sal_trig
  AFTER UPDATE OF shi_status ON TAB1
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.status = 'ZAK')
CALL idk.log_sal_test.log_sal(1, 5, 8);
```

Then i make this update so trigger enters:

```
UPDATE TAB1
SET status = 'ZAK'
where id = '99999999';
```

Trigger starts, but I've got an error:

```
[2018-06-21 10:24:58] [99999][29540] ORA-29540: class com.sth.ctt.business.cases.control.CaseWatch does not exist
[2018-06-21 10:24:58] ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'IDK.SAL_TRIG'
```

In `spring-boot` application that is writing/reading from database I've got:

```
package com.sth.ctt.business.cases.control;

public class CaseWatch {

    public static void logSal (int empID, float oldSal, float newSal)
    {
        System.out.println("jestem"); // does not trigger
        System.out.println("jestem2");
    }
}
```

I don't want to load this class into database.
I want that Oracle will call my external method from spring-boot aplication. How can i make it work?
My application runs on `localhost` but DB itself is on `remote server`(I need to type IP other than `localhost` for DB).
I would like that it executed method from spring-boot application context - so in jar / war that is running. Not just a file as such.

Comment: I don't know if its possible or not, but from what I have seen, we always compile java classes into database. if we have to execute them via PL/SQL etc.

Comment: You can have a look at - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_ex.htm looks like its possible and this link also has examples

Comment: Sounds like the database itself can't see the external Java package; i.e. the JAR it's in isn't in Oracle's classpath when the DB starts? Or maybe you can look at [the `create java .. using bfile ... ` method] to access it from a directory?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have running spring-boot application and execute `update` from DB console. Not sure how to make it `visible`.

Comment: @AlexPoole My application runs on `localhost` but DB itself is on `remote server` (need to type `IP` other than `localhost`).

Comment: @AlexPoole I would like that it executed method from spring-boot application context - so in `jar` / `war` that is running. Not just a `file` as such.